# how can i detect link on uilabel programatically?

Tags: url, hyperlink, uilabel

I want to detect URL like www.google.com from UILabel. How can I do this ??

I have made a textfield and what ever is typed in it, is displayed on label. I want to detect URl from this text. Pls Help

```
(void)displayMethod:btnOk
{
    name = textField.text;

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 150, 280, 80)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = name;
    label.numberOfLines=0;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSURL's URLWithString returns nil if the string passed does not contain a valid URL. So simply check the return value of your label's text string to see if the URL is valid or not.

Here is some sample code.

```
if([NSURL URLWithString:label.text] == nil){
  //sring inside the label is not a valid url
}
else {
  //string inside is a valid url
}

//If you want to disable highlights, and hyperlinks it is possible to do 
//it with UITextViews by doing something like this
myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

Comment: @user3193017 you asked us how to detect the url from a given string and the answer above answers that buddy. If you also want to disable the link displayed on your label then please update your question too. I will update my answer for you now that covers the disabling of hyperlinks :D